# How to get the values on the other form

Tags: hooks, forms

I would like to save the form field values by using `mymodule_admin()`. How can I get the values saved in `mymodule_admin()` on the other form without using the database?

```
function subscription_admin() {
  $form = array();
  $form['txtSubscription'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Enter The Subscription Amount'),
        '#default_value' => variable_get('txtSubscription', '500'),
        '#size' => 20,
        '#maxlength' => 20,
        '#description' => t('This text field tells the subscription generation amount'),
        '#required' => TRUE,
  );
return system_settings_form($form);
}
```

This is the admin view form. If the administrator user changes the value, it would be changed.

Comment: As per my understanding you have retrieve the value which is entered in subscription_admin() correct?

Comment: yeah!! you are right !!

Comment: use the below answer is correct by using variable_get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mymodule_admin()` is not the function that does the trick saving your variables. It's [`system_settings_form()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/system_settings_form/7).

You can retrieve variables saved by `system_settings_form()` using [variable_get()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_get/7) function.
So, in your case, you can get the value like this:

```
$txtSubscription = variable_get('txtSubscription', '');
```

Second parameter of the `variable_get` function will be returned if the variable is **not set** (not necessarily empty).
Notice that we used the same key as your form array's key.

During the Drupal bootrap, *all* variables are loaded to `$GLOBALS` (Thanks to kiamlaluno for the correction). Do not use this to store all your data because all of these variables will be loaded on every bootstrap.